# Excel CountIfs multiple criteria with range or condition with cell reference

Tags: excel-formula

I have 2 columns in an excel file, I need to get the count if column A values any match values in a named column range and column B values match any values in a named column range. In a different sheet, I have columns C and D for named ranges.

### Sheet1

A        |     B

---

a1       |     b1
a2       |     b2
a3       |     b1
a1       |     b3

### Sheet2

C | D

---

a1      |  b1

a2      |  b2

Now, I want to get all the count of A match values in C and B matching values in D. The return values should be 2.

I have tried with `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(A:A,C1:C4,B:B,D1:D4))`, but this always returns 0

Comment: works for me: https://imgur.com/EoDOoCy

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly this should be ok for the count of A

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A1:A4,C1)
```

and this should be ok for the count of B

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!B1:B4,D1)
```